# Density of zero modes

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact smooth Riemannian manifold with a smooth boundary. Let $\{(\lambda_k,\phi_k)\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be the spectral data on $(M,g)$, namely an orthonormal basis for $L^2(M)$ consisting of the Dirichlet eigenfunctions of $-\Delta_g$ on $M$. Finally, let $U \Subset M$ be an open proper subset.

For any **non-zero**$f\in C^{\infty}_0(U)$ let
$$\rho =  \limsup_{n\to \infty} \,n^{-1}\,|\{ k=1,2,\ldots,n\,:\, \int_M f\,\phi_k \,dV_g=0\}|$$
Is there a constant $0<C<1$ indepenent of $f$ (thus only depending on $U$, $M$ and $g$) such that $\rho <C$? Obviously, $C=1$ works but I am interested in $C<1$.

I would appreciate any references on similar themed topics of research.

Comment: @Asaf ??? The OP required the support to be strictly smaller than the whole space, didn't he?

Comment: The case of $M=S^1$ (with the usual metric) follows from a version of Carlson's theorem